# Find the mean of each boxes in an image in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have this image with 9 small boxes(black and white boxes) each of width = x and height =y. I need the mean of pixel values of each small boxes.

Initially I converted the image to array as

```
image = cv2.imread('x.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

[image]

here is what i tried but there are errors.

```
box_pixels = []
temp = []
p, q, r, s = 0, x, 0, y
while q <= gray.shape[0]:
    temp.append([])
    while s <= gray.shape[1]:
        for i in range(p, q):
            for j in range(r, s):
                temp.append(gray[i][j])
        r = s
        s = s+y
    p = q
    q = q + x
    box_pixels.append(temp)

print(box_pixels)
```

i can't figure out what to do for mean?

Comment: That sounds like a kernel problem. What are you trying to ultimately do? Blur the image?

Comment: No,not about blurring if i get mean of a box i can consider it as pixel of that box(like being black box or white box)

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, you're basically just wanting to resize the image using the mean? Why not just use the `cv2.resize` with your choice of interpolator?

Comment: It's definitely possible to do what you're wanting to do with two nested loops. However, that efficiency would not be amazing because it would required lots of mods. Doing a 4x nested loop is not necessarily inefficient, though. If you're iterating over each box in the outer two loops (y, x), and then iterating through those boxes in the inner two, then you're only visiting each pixel once, which is still efficient.

Comment: if i resize the image will i get proper results?.Like If i resize as you say i will get image with just 9 pixels with each pixel representing each box in above image

Comment: Yessir! I just read up some of the documentation, and the interpolator you want is `INTER_AREA`, which does exactly what you are currently doing, except it handles a few more cases. I'll write some code in an answer as an example.

Answer (score 1):

So all you're really trying to do is scale the image down. Let's say our image is 256x256 pixels, and we want to scale it down to 32x32 pixels. That means we're going to 1/8 the size of the original (32/256). That also means that each box will be 8x8 pixels. So, to perform the resize:

```
image = cv2.imread('x.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
resized = cv2.resize(gray, None, fx=32/256, fy=32/256, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

That should give you the idea of what you need to do with the width/height coordinates to calculate the right resize value.

Comment: Its good to resize but it wouldn't help in conditions like if there are errors in image like blur image or image that is not clear as the above one as in such cases the pixels are different in the same small boxes